# Ansible to wait until connection is valid

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to use ansible to download a certificate from an API, and here is what I'm using:

```yaml
- name: Get Shipa API address
  shell: kubectl --namespace=shipa-system get svc shipa-ingress-nginx -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
  environment:
    TERM: dumb      
  register: shipa_api 
  until: shipa_api.stdout | ipaddr
  retries: 5
  delay: 90
```

This works great to wait until the API IP is available and on the next step, I do this:

```yaml
- name: Add Shipa as a target on CLI
  shell: shipa target add {{ cluster_name }} {{ shipa_apiaddr }} -s
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  no_log: False
```

This step calls that API IP and tries to retrieve a certificate from IP, but the problem is that even though the IP may be available, the API service might not be running yet, so I get this as a response:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "shipa target add s12-rc4-t2 35.247.97.88 -s", "delta": "0:00:00.164987", "end": "2020-12-18 11:53:23.177987", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-12-18 11:53:23.013000", "stderr": "Error: Get \"https://35.247.97.88:8081/certificates/ca\": dial tcp 35.247.97.88:8081: connect: connection refused", "stderr_lines": ["Error: Get \"https://35.247.97.88:8081/certificates/ca\": dial tcp 35.247.97.88:8081: connect: connection refused"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Is there a way for Ansible to check if the API service is available before trying the next step "Add Shipa as a target on CLI" so it doesn't fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the module [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) in order to wait for a specific IP/port couple to accept connections.

So something like:

```yaml
- wait_for:
    host: 35.247.97.88
    port: 8081
    delay: 10
```

---

So in your case, I guess:

```yaml
- wait_for:
    ## Depending on what is in the variable shipa_apiaddr 
    ## (just the ip or ip:port)
    # host: "{{ shipa_apiaddr.split(':').0 }}"  
    host: "{{ shipa_apiaddr }}" 
    ## Depending on what is in the variable shipa_apiaddr 
    ## (just the ip or ip:port)
    ## Not sure how you should prevent hardcoding it based on your question 
    # port: "{{ shipa_apiaddr.split(':').1 }}" 
    port: 8081 
    delay: 10
```